# Avoid Android audio stream decrease volume while playing other stream

Tags: android, audio, stream, headset

I'm using Android TextToSpeech to read the caller name and I'd like to play it only through headset (if connected).

It works if I specify `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL as TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM`. I can hear the ringtone from phone speaker and ringtone + tts from headset.

But I have a problem with this way...

In the headset, when TTS says something, the ringtone decreases volume and I can hear only TTS. After TTS ends, the ringtone volume increases to its previous level. That's ok. The problem is that the ringtone decreases volume also in speaker, and so you can't hear anything while TTS is speaking (only in headset).

Is there a way to allow different sounds to be played at the same time? If not, can I route `STREAM_VOICE_CALL` to headset and `STREAM_RING` to the speaker?